# Borland error that works in Microsoft: Couldn't find a match for 'ifstream::open'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++builder, ifstream

I want to read in a text file that has the name: abc.txt

The text file contains just a simple a, b, and c, each on their own line.

When I compile this using a Microsoft compiler, it compiles with no problem at all and I get output that I expect (see below):

```
a
b
c
(blank line here)
```

Here's the Borland compile line that I'm using:

bcc32 -w -ebor.exe main.cpp

Here's my main.cpp file that I'm using:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
void printout(const std::string &file);

int main(void)
{
  printout("abc.txt");
  return 0;
}

void printout(const std::string &file)
{
  std::ifstream words;
  std::string   str;

  words.open(file);

  while(!words.eof())
  {
    std::getline(words, str);
    std::cout << str << "\n";
  }

  words.close();
}
```

The exact error that I'm getting in Borland is as follows:

**Error E2285 main.cpp 17: Could not find a match for 'ifstream::open(const std::string)' in function printout(const std::string &)**

I'm also getting a warning, but it seems like the only reason it's happening is due to the error preventing 'file' from being used:

Warning W8057 main.cpp 26: Parameter 'file' is never used in function printout(const std::string &)

Any help would be most appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Note: `while (!words.eof())` is wrong, you may get a garbage output for the last line of the file. Change to `while (std::getline(words, str))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before C++11, [`std::ifstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) required a `const char *`.  Use this.

```
words.open( file.c_str() );
```

Comment: MS compilers (pre-C++11) have an extension to allow the `std::string` version.